# Solving the forced damped oscillator, and finding maximum amplitude

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, harmonic-analysis

I am finding only a particular solution of the equation

$$y''+2\gamma y'+\Omega^2y=F\cos(\omega t)$$

which I do by assuming a solution of the form $Ae^{i\omega t}$, solving the associated equation for $A$, and then finding the real part.  At the end of that process I obtain that

$$A = \frac{F}{\Omega^2-\omega^2+2i\omega\gamma}$$

which I suspect is correct.  To find the real part of $Ae^{i\omega t}$ then involves a fairly hairy complex division problem, but I do eventually get the solution as this monster:

$$y=\frac{F\left([\Omega^2-\omega^2]\cos \omega t + [2\omega\gamma]\sin\omega t\right)}{(\Omega^2-\omega^2)^2+4\omega^2\gamma^2}$$

I next want to find the magnitude at which this reaches a maximum amplitude, and this is where I start to kind of lose spirits.  I know I could use the formula $B\cos x+C\sin x = \sqrt{B^2+C^2}\sin (x+\alpha)$ to express this as a single sinusoid with its magnitude explicit.  But that seems like a lot of work given how messy this already is.  Is there a simpler solution?

In particular, I'm wondering: Can I just try to maximize $A$?  If so, how?  Do I minimize the denominator by taking the derivative of its magnitude and setting it to 0?  All of the sudden that too sounds less appealing.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

(Also, if the math here got bad because I made a mistake, that'd be great to know too.  So far I'm missing the reason why the prof chose to call the damping coefficient $2\gamma$ for instance, which makes me think I'm missing something or did something wrong.)

Comment: minimise the denominator with respect to the driving frequency?

Comment: @KirylPesotski that was my guess, not sure if it's the right thing to do

Comment: If you write down the characteristic equation for the homogeneous problem, you get a quadratic. The factor of 2 removes the factor of $1/2$ that appears because of the quadratic equation. It's just a matter of convenience really

Comment: I guess you want to find the resonance driving frequency, that is the one which maximises the amplitude. When damping is absent that is just the frequency coinciding with the natural one $\omega_{resonance}=\Omega$, the amplitude blows up to infinity. with the damping present, you have $\frac{d}{d\omega}(4\omega^{2}\gamma^{2}+(\Omega^{2}-\omega^{2})^{2})=8\omega\gamma^{2}-4\omega(\Omega^{2}-\omega^{2})^{2})=0$. So, $\omega_{resonance}=2\gamma^{2}-\Omega^{2}$

Comment: @KirylPesotski I think you forgot to reduce the exponent while computing the derivative on the second term.

Comment: @KirylPesotski Also $\omega = 0$ is a solution.  Then the corresponding amplitudes are $\Omega^2$ and some really monsterous expression, and I need to pick the larger of the two.

Comment: Yes, I haven't written that, but the answer is correct.

Comment: You need the denominator to be minimum so look at the sign of the second derivative as usual.